# How to download IP2Location database with curl

Tags: curl, download, ip2location

I'm trying to download a database from IP2Location using the curl command they provide. I am registered so I have a valid token. The command they give is

```
    curl -o {LOCAL_FILE_NAME} "https://www.ip2location.com/download?token={DOWNLOAD_TOKEN}&file={DATABASE_CODE}"
```

Here's the code I am using, except for my token:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.ip2location.com/download?token={mytoken}&file={DB1LITEBIN}");

    $dbfile = curl_exec($curl);

    if (curl_errno($curl)) {
     echo 'err '.curl_errno($curl);
    }                  

    curl_close($curl);

    $file = 'db_download.bin';  
    $mode = 'w';

     if (($fp = fopen($file , $mode))) {    
       $fout = fwrite($fp, $dbfile);
       fclose($fp);  
    }
```

The script runs without error but the file that is downloaded is just the page not found page of their site. I get the same page not found if I use the url in a browser. Can someone please point out my mistake?

Comment: please add a language tag for what language the answer is supposed to be in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following. Note that you will be downloading a zip file containing the bin file.

```
<?php

//The resource that we want to download.
$fileUrl = 'https://www.ip2location.com/download?token=XXXXXXXXXX&file=DB1LITEBIN';

//The path & filename to save to.
$saveTo = 'db_download.zip';

//Open file handler.
$fp = fopen($saveTo, 'w+');

//If $fp is FALSE, something went wrong.
if($fp === false){
    throw new Exception('Could not open: ' . $saveTo);
}

//Create a cURL handle.
$ch = curl_init($fileUrl);

//Pass our file handle to cURL.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

//Timeout if the file doesn't download after 20 seconds.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

//Execute the request.
curl_exec($ch);

//If there was an error, throw an Exception
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
}

//Get the HTTP status code.
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

//Close the cURL handler.
curl_close($ch);

//Close the file handler.
fclose($fp);

if($statusCode == 200){
    echo 'Downloaded!';
} else{
    echo "Status Code: " . $statusCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); and it work, thank you

Comment: Don't add _thanks_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](/help/why-vote).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).